# how can we get QuickGraph for .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, quickgraph

We would like to start using [QuickGraph](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/).

Unfortunately, we are stuck on .NET 3.5 for the time being and it appears that QuickGraph is only available via NuGet and against .NET 4.0 or above.

We have tried downloading the latest code, but it seems to be only for portable library (which is great) and there does not seem to be an easy way to just recompile against .NET 3.5

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source on codeplex](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) shows a 2.0 directory containing a Vs2008 QuickGraph.sln. You should try to compile that one.

The history on the [homepage](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/) shows that 2.0 support was dropped with the first release to Nuget. I guess they jumped straight to 4.0, but have you tried to install version [3.3.51106.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages/QuickGraph/3.3.51106.0)?